# How to force stop Intent Service in progress?

Tags: android, service, intentservice

I have an intent service which downloads several gigabytes of videos. I have a "Stop" button, to stop the download if accidentally hit "Start" or whatever. I know this has been asked a couple of times but with no working answer for me.

I try to call `stopService()`, doesn't work. That just calls `IntentService.OnDestroy()`.
I tried to call `stopSelf()` inside `onDestroy`, doesn't work either.

I tried to have something like a flag, but onHandleIntent doesn't get called if its already running, it waits till current work is finished and executes then. And even if this would have worked, I would have to have something like a giant if statement, that sucks

Is my only option really to rewrite it to a regular Service?

//Answer

```
public class SyncService extends IntentService {

    boolean isCanceled;

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        if (intent.hasExtra("action")) {

            // Set the canceling flag
            isCanceled= intent.getStringExtra("action").equals("cancel");

        }
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

        // Clean up the possible queue
        if (intent.hasExtra ("action")) {
            boolean cancel = intent.getStringExtra ("action"). Equals ("cancel");
            if (cancel) {
                return;
            }
        }

        ...

        Get your inputStream from HttpUrlConnection or whatever

        ...

        while ((bytesRead = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            if (isCanceled) {
                isCanceled = false;
                break;
            }

            ...
        }

    }
}
```

And trigger it with

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, SyncService.class);
intent.putExtra("action", "cancel");
context.startService(intent);
```

Comment: You might consider removing your solution from your question, and instead providing it as a solution.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have two separate issues, I would think:

1. How to stop the current download
2. How to stop queued up downloads, that should execute after the current one completes

The first one is going to have to be "something like a flag", that you check as you download the data. Otherwise, nothing is going to stop your download operation. If you are using a typical `HttpUrlConnection` recipe, you check that flag in your loop where you read from the HTTP `InputStream` and write to your `FileOutputStream`. You set that flag via a call to `startService()` with a particular `Intent` structure, identifying it as a "cancel" operation. You would need to override `onStartCommand()` in your `IntentService`, look at the `Intent`, use it to set the flag if it is the cancel `Intent`, or chain to the superclass for any other sort of `Intent`.

If you *also* may have other commands queued up (scenario #2), you would need to check that flag at the top of `onHandleIntent()` as well.

Comment: Yes exactly as you say. If I rewrite it to a Service, would I be able to forcefully shut it down or would it be the same thing as here?

Comment: @VlastoBennyLava: It would be the same thing as here, more or less. You would have better ability to perhaps use `stopService()` and `onDestroy()` to set the flag, but you'd have to manage your own background thread and work queue.

Comment: I edited my question with answer pseudo code, you might want to check it out. Thanks

Comment: @VlastoBennyLava: I would use an `AtomicBoolean` rather than a `boolean`, as it will be manipulated on parallel threads. Otherwise, that should work.

Answer (score 2):

Given that you haven't posted *how* you're handling the video download exactly, this may not work (there would be some sort of loop inside `onHandleIntent` where the downloads are executed). You can use a static class variable inside the `IntentService` that holds the Stop/Start state of the download, so that it can be set by an `Activity`. Then, inside `onHandleIntent`, you would have to routinely check the state so it would know when to cancel the operations.