# Android download long file with options to cancel

Tags: java, android, android-intent, download

I was using Android download manager. Then, I saw wits buggy, so basically I went for an intent service to download a file, and from intent service I am updating a progress dialog with a handler.

In the intent service, I am opeining an input stream and writing the output file in the download folder using an output stream.

All is ok right now, but my question is how can I offer users the option to cancel the download in the middle? My code in onHandleIntent is the following.

```
        InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(footyDirectory.toString()+"/demo.mp4");

        byte data[] = new byte[1024];
        long total = 0;
        int count;
        while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
            total += count;
            // publishing the progress....
            Bundle resultData = new Bundle();
            resultData.putInt("progress" ,(int) (total * 100 / fileLength));
            receiver.send(UPDATE_PROGRESS, resultData);
            output.write(data, 0, count);
        }

        output.flush();
        output.close();
        input.close();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to force stop Intent Service in progress?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16093919/how-to-force-stop-intent-service-in-progress)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare a `boolean` vairable `isCanceled` to use inside your loop and set it to true when
user cancel download.

```
 while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
        if(isCanceled){
           //Do your work here (close stream, delete temp file, send broadcast...)
           break;
        }
        total += count;
        // publishing the progress....
        Bundle resultData = new Bundle();
        resultData.putInt("progress" ,(int) (total * 100 / fileLength));
        receiver.send(UPDATE_PROGRESS, resultData);
        output.write(data, 0, count);
 }
```

Comment: i thought about it earlier,but my concern is,as i'm using intentservice,how to change the isCancelled boolean value from the activity.

i know storing it in sharedpreference could be one solution,but is there any alternative?

Comment: @ShofiqulAlam you can send `Broadcast` to notify your `IntentService` about cancling download.

Answer (score 2):

Have a variable canceled in your intentService.  When the user wants to cancel it, set canceled to true.  In your while loop, check the value of canceled.  If its true, exit the loop and clean up and do any cleanup you need to delete partial files, remove notifications, etc.