# During App uninstall ,How to cancel the Download?

Tags: android, android-service, background-process, android-download-manager

In my app i have started download service,it is working fine in background.During download my testing team doing  force stop and clear data or Uninstall.But After uninstall or clear data still my Download service is running in background.During download i have installed the same app again but it is misbehaving some thing.While uninstall or clear data or force stop i have to cancel the download How?

```
public class FileDownloaderService extends IntentService {


    private CarcarePreferences preferences;

    public FileDownloaderService() {
        super("FileDownloaderService");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        preferences = CarcarePreferences.getCarcarePreferencesObject(getApplicationContext());
        DBHelper.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).open();

        downloadManager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

        if (extras == null) {
            return;
        }

        if (extras.containsKey("ResultReceiver")) {
            resultReceiver = extras.getParcelable("ResultReceiver");
        }

        if (extras.containsKey("ContentToDownload")) {
            contentToDownload = extras.getInt("ContentToDownload");
        } else {
            return;
        }

        if (contentToDownload != Carcare.ContentToDownload.IMAGES) {
            isDefaultVehicle = extras.getBoolean("IsDefaultVehicle");
            fetchVehicle();
        }

        switch (contentToDownload) {
            case Carcare.ContentToDownload.HEADUNIT_IMAGES:
                if (extras.containsKey("HeadUnits")) {
                    headUnits = (ArrayList<Unit>) extras.getSerializable("Units");
                    downloadHeadUnits();
                    resultReceiver.send(0, null);
                }
                break;


        }
    }

    private void fetchVehicle() {
        Object[] objects;

        if (isDefaultVehicle) {
            objects = DBAdapter.getAllVehicles(preferences.getDefaultModel(),
                    preferences.getDefaultYear(), isDefaultVehicle);
        } else {
            objects = DBAdapter.getAllVehicles(preferences.getCurrentModel(),
                    preferences.getCurrentYear(), isDefaultVehicle);
        }

        vehicle = (Vehicle) objects[0];
    }

    private void downloadHeadUnits() {
        mHeadUnitDir = SdUtils.getDir(this);
        //clearHeadUnits();

        for (CUnit unit : Units) {

            String fileName = mDir + "/" + unit.getGuid() + ".png";
            InputStream stream = null;
            final HttpGet httpRequest = new HttpGet(unit.getHuImageUrl());
            httpRequest.setHeader(HTTP.CONN_DIRECTIVE, HTTP.CONN_KEEP_ALIVE);
            try {
                File file = new File(fileName);
                if (!file.exists()) {
                    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file); //openFileOutput(fileName);
                    stream = new DefaultHttpClient().execute(httpRequest).getEntity().getContent();
                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalStateException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private void download() {
        cancelDownload(Carcare.FileType.QRG, vehicle.getPath());
        deleteDoc(vehicle.getQRGPath());

        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(vehicle.getUrl()));
        request.setDestinationUri(Uri.parse(vehicle.getPath()));
        request.setTitle("Unit");
        request.setDescription("Quick Reference Guide");

        preferences.setDownloadID(Carcare.FileType.QRG, downloadManager.enqueue(request));
    }
}
```

Comment: **While uninstall the service is running?** ,that's not possible even in a dream.While uninstallation of the application, all the resources related to the application are removed with in an instant..

Comment: @nobalG it is happening ,by using intent service only i have started the service

Comment: Can you come up with some source code of how have you started the download.

Comment: Use flag `stopWithTask="true"` for Service in manifest

Comment: @MysticMagic i have checked with your code...service is not canceled

Comment: Ohk.. try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16093999/1777090)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [remove()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html#remove%28long...%29) method of the DownloadManager.

It says:

> **public int remove (long... ids) Added in API level 9**
>
> Cancel downloads and remove them from the download manager. Each
>   download will be stopped if it was running, and it will no longer be
>   accessible through the download manager. If there is a downloaded
>   file, partial or complete, it is deleted. Parameters ids  the IDs of
>   the downloads to remove Returns
>
> ```
> the number of downloads actually removed
> ```

**Edit**

To intercept your application uninstall take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8687069/2319390).

Comment: @Boopathi I've edited my answer to include how to intercept app unistall see if that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You must use a `Service`.

In the Service's `onDestroy()`, you can write the code to finish the `DownloadManager`.

The `Service` will be killed before the app is about to uninstall.
This way the Download will stop.

Comment: Service how to get call the ondestroy method while uninstalling